# Starting higher-level players in Hoard of the Dragon Queen

Tags: dnd-5e, gm-techniques, character-levels

I'm a newbie GM running the 5e starter set adventure (Lost Mines). My players are progressing well through it, and are at 3rd level closing in on 4th level. Assuming they make it through the adventure (and get to 5th level) the intended plan is to start on Hoard of the Dragon Queen.

But HotDQ is a level 1-7 adventure, with the adventure starting with level 1 players. Some options that I've read about:

- Have the players roll new characters (not preferred because they're quite invested in their current ones)
- adjust all the encounters to handle higher-level players (more work for me, and something I'm not very confident about doing properly)
- start the players somewhere in the middle (but then they lose the backstory of what's been happening.

What would people recommend ?

Comment: Though this may be a duplicate, never fear—duplicates are useful and appreciated, as they make it easier for others with the same question to find answers. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks. I suspected it might be, but sometimes it's harder to search.